# Сортировка в C++

Tags: c++, ооп, сортировка, vector

Помогите разобраться с кодом. Программа считывает из входного файла с первой строки количество элементов массива, а со второй строки входного файла сами элементы. Все считывается в вектор, а затем все элементы сортируются и выводятся в выходной файл. Мне не понятны в этой программе некоторые вещи:

1. Я не понимаю, как именно здесь работает < algorithm >, зачем его подключили?
2. Зачем здесь using std::string?
3. Почему здесь в auto iter записывается результат сложения первого элемента вектора с его количеством, деленным на 2?
4. Векторы v1 и v2 создаются, чтобы занести в каждый из них две половинки массива(одна половинка в v1, а другая в v2)? vector v1(vec.begin(), iter); - это же значит, что в векторе v1 находятся все числа, находящиеся в диапазоне от начального элемента массива до значения переменной iter и с v2 все аналогично?
5. Функция mergeSort2 вызывается дважды внутри самой себя, чтобы отсортировать две половинки массива?
6. Мы же очищаем вектор(vec.clear()), чтобы сработала сначала mergeSort2(v1), а затем mergeSort2(v2)?
7. Я правильно понимаю, что в последней строке функции mergeSort2 объединяются два диапазона(первый из v1, а второй из v2)в один диапазон, а back_inserter(vec) записывает его в вектор vec с конца?

```c
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <fstream>
using std::cout; using std::endl;
using std::string; using std::vector;
template<typename T>
void mergeSort2(vector<T>& vec) {
    if (vec.size() <= 1)
        return;

    auto iter = vec.begin() + vec.size() / 2;
    vector<T> v1(vec.begin(), iter);
    vector<T> v2(iter, vec.end());

    mergeSort2(v1);
    mergeSort2(v2);

    vec.clear();
    std::merge(v1.begin(), v1.end(), v2.begin(), v2.end(), std::back_inserter(vec));
}
int main()
{
    std::ifstream in("sort.in");
    std::ofstream out("sort.out");
    int n;
    in >> n;
    vector<int> vec1(n);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        in >> vec1[i];
    mergeSort2(vec1);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        out << vec1[i] << " ";
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

В вашем примере представлена реализация [алгоритма сортировки слиянием](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BC)
Отвечая на ваши вопросы:

1. `<algorithm>`  - нужен чтобы вызвать `std::merge`;
2. `using std::string` - можно удалить, ни на что не повлияет;
3. почитайте про алгоритм сортировки слиянием по ссылке выше - поймете;
4. да, верно;
5. да, две очередные половинки, это называется рекурсия;
6. нет, мы очищаем его, чтобы положить туда результат работы `std::merge`;
7. почти правильно, только не "с конца", а в конец. Элементы массивов `v1` и `v2` будут добавляться в конец массива `vec`;